# Data structure and patients records

Tags: c, data-structures

Computerizing health records could make it easier for the patients to share their health profiles and histories among their various health care professionals. A health clinic needs your help to computerize the patients' health records. The patient's records consist of first name, middle name, last name (including SR. JR., etc), gender, date of birth, height (in inches), weight (in pounds). The clinic requires  the following features of the program:

1. read existing record from a file where each patient record is one line entry separating each data with comma
2. add additional records to file
3. a function to calculate and return patients age in 3yrs
4. a function that calculates body mass index with the given formula BMI=(weight-in-pounds X 703)/(height-in-inches X 2) or BMI = (weight-in-kgs)/(height-in-meters X 2)
5. search patient's name and display patient's information  with age and BMI value including category
6. update patient's information on date of birth, height and/or weight and save updates to file
7. display all records in tabular format

So far what I have made is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
FILE*fin;
char name,fname,mname,lname,ename,gender,ch,getch,patient;
int dob,month,day,year,height,weight;
fin=fopen("oldrec.c","w");{
printf("Error: File does not exists");
return 0;
}
{
printf("Add Record? y/n");
ch=toupper(getch);
if(ch='y')
break;
}while (1);

struct patient{
char name;
char fname[20];
char mname[20];
char lname[20];
char gender;
int dob;
int month;
int day;
int year;
int height;
int weight;

printf("/n Patient's Name");
printf("First Name: ");
scanf("%s", &patient.fname);
printf("Middle Name: ");
scanf("%s", &patient.mname);
printf("Last Name: ");
scanf("%s", &patient.lname);
printf("Gender: ");
scanf("%s", &patient.gender);
printf("Date of Birth");
printf("Month: ");
scanf("&d", &patient.month);
printf("Day: ");
scanf("&d", &patient.day);
printf("Year: ");
scanf("%s", %patient.year);
printf("Height: ");
scanf("%d", & patient.height);
printf("Weight: ");
scanf("%d", &patient.weight);

}
```

I have made another file already, but when I run the codes, it says "Error: File does not exist". What is wrong, and what are the codes for the other problems? Please help me! This is our final requirement on my data structure subject.

Comment: please edit your tags to either c++ or c

Comment: A health clinic needs *my* help? Oh boy!

Comment: You need to please format that code and make it able to be compiled. Then you need to ask for help on a specific problem not "what are the codes for the other problems?" You shouldn't be asking people to do your homework for you. How do you expect to learn?

Comment: Please improve formatting of text too.

Answer (score 2):

```
fin=fopen("oldrec.c","w");{              // no if 
   printf("Error: File does not exists");      // all statements will be executed 
   return 0;                   // and function will terminate here
}
```

Ofcourse it will show that message , no condition . No matter if `fopen` is successful without `if` all statements will be executed.

Put it in a `if` block witn a condition .

Write like this -

```
fin=fopen("oldrec.c","w");             
if(fin==NULL){                  // check if fin is NULL 
     printf("Error: File does not exists");
     return 0;
}
```

Other problems are these statements -

```
scanf("%s", &patient.fname);
...
scanf("%s", &patient.mname);
...
scanf("%s", &patient.lname);
...     
scanf("%s", &patient.gender);      // use %c for reading char variable 
...
scanf("%s", %patient.year);        // use %d to read int 
            ^ whats this
```

Write these statemetns like this -

```
scanf("%s", patient.fname);
...
scanf("%s", patient.mname);
...
scanf("%s", patient.lname);
...     
scanf("%c", &patient.gender);       
...
scanf("%d", &patient.year);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks better now, in my opinion. :-)

Comment: @graced `%s` expects `char *` and when you pass array it decays to pointer . So If  you pass its address it will be of type `char **` which is not required .